# How 'local' are function parameters in a PowerShell module

Tags: powershell, module, parameters, scope

I have found a behavior in PowerShell that surprises me and for which I am looking for an explanation. Please consider the following PowerShell module named *testParameter*:

`testParameter.psd1`:

```
@{
   RootModule         = 'testParameter.psm1'
   ModuleVersion      = '0.1'

   FunctionsToExport  = @(
      'get-embeddedString'
   )
}
```

`testParameter.psm1`:

```
set-strictMode -version 3

function embed-string {

   param (
      [string] $pre,
      [string] $post
   )

  "$($pre)$text$($post)"
}


function get-embeddedString {

   param (
      [string] $text
   )

   return embed-string '>>> ' ' <<<'
}
```

When I call `get-embeddedString foo`, the function returns (or the console prints):

```
>>> foo <<<
```

I am surprised because this string is rendered in the function `embed-string` which does not declare a local variable named `$text`, does not have a parameter with that name and does not assign a value to it before it is used and I have expected the function to throw a *The variable '$text' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.* error.

Apparently, `embed-string` chooses to use the value that `$text` has in `get-embeddedString` which I assume is in a different and unrelated scope.

I don't understand what's going on here and where the relevant documentation for this behavior is found.

Comment: Where did you set `$text`? in the global scope (`$Global:Text`)? [Functions from a module do not run in a child scope of the calling scope. Modules have their own session state that is linked to the global scope. All module code runs in a module-specific hierarchy of scopes that has its own root scope.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.1#powershell-scopes)

Comment: I didn't set `$text` anywhere which is why I am puzzled. I just double checked: `$global:text` is undefined before and after running `get-embeddedText foo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested/Child functions have access to all the parent function's variables. You can even modify them in the child scope and they are returned to the original value in the parent.

```
function embed-string {
   param (
      [string] $pre,
      [string] $post
   )
    Write-Host $MyInvocation.BoundParameters
    Write-Host $MyInvocation.UnboundArguments

    Write-Host $text
    $text = "bar"

    "$($pre)$text$($post)"
}

function get-embeddedString {

    param (
       [string] $text
    )
    
    embed-string '>>> ' ' <<<'

    Write-Host $text
}
```

Output

```
[pre, >>> ] [post,  <<<]

foo
>>> bar <<<
foo
```

If you want to persist a change to a variable in the child function, you can use `Set-Variable -Name text -Option AllScope`.

[Link about Nested Functions, applies to Child Functions too](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/jj574123(v=ws.11)#using-parameters-and-variables-in-nested-functions-and-workflows)

Answer (score 3):

[about_Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Scopes) is the official conceptual help topic describing *scopes* in PowerShell (which, typically, but not exclusively, relate to *variables*), but let me provide a concise explanation:

- As most shells do, **PowerShell uses *dynamic* rather than *lexical* scoping**.

  - That is, rather than variables being visible only to the enclosing *lexical construct*, such as a function definition, variable visibility depends on the *runtime call stack*. In other words: **what variables a given function or script sees depends on *who called it***.
  - **Unless a caller explicitly *hides* variables with the `$private:` scope, all *descendant scopes* see them by default**.
- Therefore, because your `embed-string` function was called from your `get-embeddedString` function and the latter defines a `$text` variable (via a *parameter* declaration in this case), that `$text` variable is also visible to `embed-string` - and would also be visible to functions called from *it* (and so on).

**Notable pitfalls**:

- **While unqualified (non-scoped) *read* access to an ancestral variable gets its value, *assigning a value* implicitly creates a new, *local* variable that *shadows* the ancestral one**.

  - E.g., `"$($pre)$text$($post)"` in your `embed-string` function *gets* the value of the ancestral `$text` variable, but if you were to execute, say, `$text = 'value'` there, you'd create a *local variable by the same name*, which is then visible to any `embed-strings` descendants on the call stack, but unrelated to the original `get-embeddedstring` `$text` variable.
- **Only scopes in the same *scope domain* (aka *session state*), in the same runspace, exhibit this relationship; *each module has its own scope domain*, and all non-module code shares a single, separate one**. The only one scope shared by all scope domains is the *global* scope, which is the *root* scope of *all* scope domains.

See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36347515/45375) for a **comprehensive overview** of PowerShell scopes.