# Why Does PowerShell Complain It Can't Retrieve a Variable?

Tags: powershell, syntax, variable-declaration, variable-initialization

I'm getting the following error message:

```
The variable '$dateTime' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
```

The error is generated by the line **[DateTime]$dateTime** in this code:

```
  [string]$registryEntry = Read-Registry -path $SCRIPT_KEY -name $key

   [DateTime]$dateTime 
   if ($null -ne $registryEntry) {
      $dateTime = [DateTime]$registryEntry
   }
   return $dateTime
```

But the error message makes no sense: I’m not trying to *retrieve* the $dateTime variable, I’m just declaring it.

I have to return a DateTime object, or $null if it’s undefined. FYI, the registry entry is the string “19 Jul 2023 05:52”

How do I make this work?

$psVersionTable:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.3.6
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.3.6
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76724156/45375):

> I’m not trying to *retrieve* the `$dateTime` variable, I’m just *declaring* it.

**PowerShell has *no* concept of mere variable *declarations*** (the only exceptions are *parameter* variables - see the [relevant section of `about_Functions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions#functions-with-parameters)).

**You can only "declare" a variable** by implicitly creating it **via *assigning a value* to it**. (If the variable already exists, it will be updated.)

Since **you want to use a *type constraint***, i.e. to limit the values the variable can hold to a given type, the **value you assign must be *of that type* or *convertible* to it**; in the simplest case:

```bash
[datetime] $dateTime = 0
```

Using `[int]` value `0` has the same effect as `[datetime]::MinValue`, as shown in Mathias' answer, given that `0` can be converted to the latter, due to PowerShell's flexible automatic type conversions (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69653097/45375)).

If you either use *no* type constraint or you use a type constraint with a .NET *reference type*, you can use `$null` for initialization; e.g.:

```bash
# No type constraint, same as [object]
$newVar = $null

# .NET reference-type type constraint
[regex] $newVar = $null
```

if `$null` is allowed as a value in a given situation, you can also use the following **single-statement idiom for initializing a variable with varying values**, so as to guarantee the variable's existence, based on using an `if` statement *as an expression*; it wouldn't work with `[datetime]`, so I'm omitting the type constraint here:

```bash
# Assigns the output from the `if` statement.
$dateTime =
  if ($null -ne $registryEntry) {
    [datetime] $registryEntry
  }
```

That is, the `if` statement's *output* becomes the value of `$datetime`, which means that if `$null -ne $registryEntry` is true, `[datetime] $registryEntry` is assigned, and `$null` otherwise.<sup>[1]</sup>

Note that a PowerShell variable *without a type constraint* is free to not only be *initialized* with a value of *an type* (including `$null`), but to also later be updated with a value of any *other* type.

As an aside:

- Another surprising aspect of variable assignments in PowerShell is that they implicitly create a *local* variable with the given name, even if a variable by that name already exists, but was defined in an *ancestral scope* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68613813/45375).

---

As for **what you tried**:

In isolation, `[DateTime]$dateTime` does the following:

- **It is a type *cast***, i.e. it tries to **convert an *existing* `$dateTime` variable to type [`[datetime]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime)** and **outputs the result**:

  - That is, you *are* trying to *retrieve* the value of variable `$dateTime`
  - If `$dateTime` does *not* exist yet...

    - ... and you have [`Set-StrictMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) `-Version 1` or higher in effect, you'll get the error you saw.
    - ... otherwise, given that referencing non-existent variables defaults to `$null`, your cast will be the equivalent of `[datetime] $null`, which fails with `Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTime"`
- In the event that such a cast succeeds its **result is sent to the success output stream**, which - in the absence of assigning it to a variable or passing it to a command -  prints to the display by default, due to PowerShell's *implicit output behavior*, explained in the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665963/45375).

---

<sup>[1] Strictly speaking, it is the "Automation null" value that is assigned, which is an "enumerable null" that behaves like `$null` in expression contexts, and like an empty enumerable in enumeration contexts - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76631985/45375) for details.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

As the error very clearly states:

> **because it has not been set.**

PowerShell doesn't really have a concept of "variable declaration" - if you want to strongly type a variable, you'll have to do it as part of an *assignment operation* - which in turn will solve your problem:

```
[string]$registryEntry = Read-Registry -path $SCRIPT_KEY -name $key

[datetime]$dateTime = [datetime]::MinValue
if ($null -ne $registryEntry) {
    $dateTime = [DateTime]$registryEntry
}

return $dateTime
```

Comment: Wow. Never would have guessed I couldn't declare a variable. Glad someone has more PSH experience than me. Thanks.Hopefully the folks who maintain PSH will come up with a better error message for this scenario.

Comment: It’s worth noting for the OP’s benefit that ```[DateTime]$dateTime``` is valid Powershell but its meaning is equivalent to ```write-output ([DateTime]$dateTime)``` which sends the result of evaluating ```[DateTime]$dateTime``` to the output stream, so it *is* trying to retrieve the variable ```$dateTime``` (which hasn’t been assigned a value yet so doesn’t exist) to calculate that result, hence the error message…