# Powershell - lambda function - modified variable scope

Tags: powershell, scope, dropbox

I have a windows form with a drop box
I need to save the selected index, but out of the lambda scope the variable is still set to zero

```
$List = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$List.text = “”
$List.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
# Add the items in the dropdown list
@("a","b") | ForEach-Object {[void] $List.Items.Add($_)}
# Select the default value
$List.SelectedIndex = 0
$List.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,$Y); $Y+=30
$List.Font = ‘Microsoft Sans Serif,10’
$selected=0
$List.add_SelectedIndexChanged({
   ([ref]$selected) = $List.SelectedIndex
})
$form.Controls.Add($List)
```

then when I show the dialog and check the value

if ($form.ShowDialog() -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
return $selected
}

variable $selected is =0 even if I select the second element in the list

am I missing something ?

thanks for your help

Comment: There is no need for the Event and $Selected is there? Just run:

$List.SelectedIndex

After the GUI has closed in your if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`([ref]$selected)` returns a [`[ref]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSReference) instance that wraps either a given value or - when casting a *variable* to it - is a dynamic reference to that variable. Either way, the wrapped value must be accessed via the `.Value` property.

Therefore, replace `([ref]$selected) = $List.SelectedIndex` with:

```bash
# Note the need for .Value
([ref] $selected).Value = $List.SelectedIndex
```

Note:

- The primary purpose of `[ref]` is to pass `ref` or `out` parameter values to .NET APIs.
- Here, you're repurposing it to refer to `$selected` variable defined in an *ancestral* (parent) scope in a manner that allows *updating* it.

  - If you did just `$selected = $List.SelectedIndex`, a *local* `$selected` variable would implicitly be created,<sup>[1]</sup> confined to the event-handler script block, given that such script blocks run in a *child scope* of the caller.

**Conceptually clearer alternatives:**

- If you know the `$selected` variable to have been created in the *script* scope (as is true in your case), you can use the `$script:` [scope specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Scopes#scope-modifiers) to refer to it, which also allows updating it:

  ```bash
  # Update the $selected variable in the *script* scope.
  $script:selected = $List.SelectedIndex
  ```
- If you want to update the variable in the *parent* scope - which may or may not the *script* scope - use the [`Set-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-variable) cmdlet with `-Scope 1`:

  ```bash
  # Update the $selected variable in the *parent* scope (-Scope 1)
  Set-Variable -Scope 1 -Name selected -Value $List.SelectedIndex
  ```
- If you want to update the variable in the *closest ancestral scope in which it was defined* (whatever scope that may be), use [`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable) and assign to the returned variable object's `.Value` property:

  ```bash
  (Get-Variable -Name selected).Value $List.SelectedIndex
  ```

  - This is the equivalent of the `([ref] $selected).Value = ...` technique; note that both techniques require that such an ancestral variable *already exist* - by contrast, the `$script:selected = ...` and `Set-Variable -Scope 1 selected ...` techniques *create the variable on demand*.

---

As for **what you tried**:

Trying the non-effective form `([ref]$selected) = $List.SelectedIndex` is understandable, and the fact that such an assignment is *seemingly* quietly ignored makes it harder to detect the problem:

In short: Your attempt created a *local* `$selected` variable containing a `[ref]` instance that (statically) wraps the value of `$List.SelectedIndex`:

- `([ref] $selected) = $List.SelectedIndex` is the same as `[ref] $selected = $List.SelectedIndex`, which is a regular *type-constrained variable assignment*.

  - That enclosing the assignment target in `(...)` is effectively ignored may be surprising, but that's how it has always worked.
- That is, variable `$selected` is assigned to, which implicitly creates a *local* variable, and - by virtue of the "cast" placed to the left of the target variable - the values it can hold are constrained to instance of `[ref]`, meaning that you can only assign values that either already *are* `[ref]` instances or are *convertible* to `[ref]`.
- Because *any* value can be converted to `[ref]` (e.g. `[ref] 1`), the newly created local `$selected` variable ended up containing a `[ref]` instance that statically wraps the assigned value, i.e. the then-current value of `$List.SelectedIndex`.

  - If we take the type-constraining aspect out of the picture, your attempt was equivalent to the following, which makes it clearer why it didn't work:

    ```bash
    # Creates *local* variable $selected, holding a [ref] instance.
    $selected = [ref] $List.SelectedIndex
    ```
- Because a local variable was accidentally created, the script-level definition of `$selected` remained unchanged.

---

<sup>[1] This perhaps surprising behavior is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68613813/45375).</sup>