# Start-Process with dot sourcing not returning?

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script (c:\startnotepad.ps1) which contains one line:

```
Start-Process c:\windows\notepad.exe
```

You'll notice it doesn't have the -Wait parameter, and hence should launch notepad.exe and continue script execution.

I call it from another PowerShell script containing the following:

```
 write-host "launching"
 $process = Start-Process -FilePath "powershell.exe" -ArgumentList "-Command","`"& { . 'c:\startnotepad.ps1'; }`"" -Wait -Passthru -ErrorAction Stop
 write-host "launched"
```

But i never see "launched" output unless I manually close the notepad.exe process?  Why is it waiting when startnotepad.ps1 has launched and finished?

UPDATE

I'm exploring using the following:

```
$ret = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { . 'c:\startnotepad.ps1'; } -ErrorAction Stop;
```

It appears to work as expected.  Will test more and review the comments/answers below too...

UPDATE 2 - TEST VARIABLE CONFLICT

c:\startnotepad.ps1

```
$animal = "cat"

function StartNotepad {
    try {
        Start-Process c:\windows\notepad.exe -Wait
        return 11
    } catch {
        return 22
    }
}
```

Host

```
 $animal = "dog"
 $ret = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { . 'c:\startnotepad.ps1'; return StartNotepad; } -ErrorAction Stop
 write-host "Animal is $animal and return code is $ret"
```

Output is cat, which shows me the variables dont conflict?

Comment: Why do you have to start another PowerShell session? Just run the script by calling it. ‍♂️

Comment: I basically need to call a function in another PowerShell script.  This is just a simplified version above, but exhibits similar behaviour.

Comment: OK, but you don't have to start another PowerShell session. You just call the second script by its relative or full path and you're done. No need to start PowerShell again with `Start-Process` That's what I meant. ‍♂️

Comment: Yes, but i need to wait for the 'other' script to finish executing.  And to process the return code from that other script.  What alternative command line do you suggest?

Comment: I just said what I recommend. Commands in PowerShell are executed sequentially unless you use tricks like `Start-Process` which allows a process to be started independently.

Comment: Hmm.  I need to dot source multiple scripts though (via a loop), and I'm not sure what variables will be declared in the dot sourced scripts.  So I'd rather run them in a separate PowerShell session to avoid variable conflicts....

Comment: As an aside: There's no reason to use `"& { ... }"` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `"..."` directly. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.

Comment: Re your update: [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) does _not_ provide the isolation you're looking for: it is the same as calling `& 'c:\startnotepad.ps1'` . Using `-NoNewScope` would provide even less isolation, and would be equivalent to `. 'c:\startnotepad.ps1'`, i.e invocation directly  in the caller's scope rather than a child scope.

Comment: What i was referring to is, in the "host" script i set (example) $animal = "cat".  And in the dot sourced script i set $animal = "dog".  At the end of the host script when using invoke-command, the value of $animal is still dog (hasn't changed to cat, even though the dot sourced script has been invoked....).  I guess what i was saying is that i don't want variables conflicting after calling invoke-command....seems to work ok in that respect?

Comment: Added an update to illustrate what i mean....

Comment: It looks like yours is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/248777): You tried to solve your problem with a call via a child _process_, whereas what you needed was a call via a child _scope_.
Please see the update to my answer, which now hopefully covers all angles. And yes, the behavior of `Start-Process`'s `-Wait` switch is what caused your original problem (as explained in the bottom section).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- As [Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf) notes, there's *usually* no good reason to run PowerShell scripts *via a separate PowerShell process*, using the PowerShell CLI ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell (Core) 7+)
- You state that your reason for doing so is to provide *isolation*, i.e. to prevent potentially *session-global* changes made by the script to invoke, such as *modifying environment variables*, setting or modifying *global variables*, loading *assemblies that conflict* with ones loaded into the caller's session, or even *changing the current location*.<sup>[1]</sup>

  - Note that [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) can *not* provide this kind of isolation, because it invariably executes the specified command *in-process* (in a *child* scope of the caller by default, and *directly in the caller's scope* with `-NoNewScope`; note that `Invoke-Command` is rarely useful for *local* calls; its main purpose is to execute code *remotely* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60980641/45375)).
  - That said, **if all you're looking for is to run your script in a child [*scope*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Scopes)** - i.e. a separate, transitory scope whose *local* variables (and aliases and function definitions) do not interfere with the caller's variables<sup>[2]</sup> - just **invoke your script *directly*** (which situationally requires explicit use of **`&`**, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-):

    ```bash
    & 'c:\startnotepad.ps1'
    ```

    - It is only if you use `.`, the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-), that a script runs *directly in the caller's scope* and therefore has direct access to its variables:

      ```bash
       # NOT what you want: directly modifies the caller's scope.
       . 'c:\startnotepad.ps1'
      ```

Since you're looking for *synchronous* execution of the `powershell.exe` child process, it's easier to call it *directly*:

```bash
write-host "launching"
# CLI parameter -Command implied.
powershell.exe { c:\startnotepad.ps1 }
write-host "launched"
```

This not only *bypasses* your original problem, but *also*:

- allows you to *directly capture* the output from the CLI call, if any.

  - Due to use of a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) (something that's only meaningfully supported when calling *from PowerShell*), you get the additional benefit of *rich type support*, albeit within the overall constraints of PowerShell's cross-process serialization - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375) for details.
- at least *abstractly* indicates success vs. failure in the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode), by mapping any *nonzero* exit code to `1`

  - You can request reporting of the *specific* exit code to the caller as follows:

    ```bash
    powershell.exe { c:\startnotepad.ps1; exit $LASTEXITCODE }
    ```
  - An even simpler way - albeit at the expense of foregoing rich type support and receiving *string* output only - is to use the `-File` CLI parameter instead:

    ```bash
    powershell.exe -File c:\startnotepad.ps1
    ```
  - For a comprehensive overview of how the PowerShell CLI sets exit codes, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57468522/45375).

---

As for **what you tried**:

**[`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)** - which is **generally the wrong tool for invoking *console* applications**, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375) - when passed the **`-Wait`** switch not only waits for the *immediate* child process to terminate *but its children too*.

This explains why the (by default) *asynchronous* `Start-Process` call used to launch `c:\windows\notepad.exe` from inside the launched script was *also* waited for in the context of the *enclosing* `Start-Process -Wait` call.

---

<sup>[1] Unfortunately, given that PowerShell - unlike POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash` - executes `.ps1` scripts *in-process*, calls to [`Set-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location) and [`Push-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/push-location) affect the *entire session* (runspace), which is why such calls are best *avoided* in scripts. That said, if changing the current location is the *only* global modification of the session made by a given script, you can save the current location before calling a script and restore it after.</sup>

<sup>[2] Whenever you assign to a variable without using a *scope prefix* such as `$script:` or `$global:` - e.g. `$foo = 1` - PowerShell creates a *local* variable. Note, however, that *descendent* scopes (e.g. calls to functions) *see* those variables, due to PowerShell's *dynamic scoping*. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68613813/45375) for background information.</sup>

Comment: " but its children too." - interesting.  That will the issue for me...!