# Powershell append value to array just adding one value

Tags: powershell

I want to get the CPU and memory stats of a process and want to add it in the CSV at regular intervals.
Following is the powershell script I wrote for that:

```
# Specify the process names
$process1Name = "abcd"
$csvFilePath = "C:\Users\johndoe\Stats.csv"
# Create an array to store process stats
$processStats = @()
# Loop to monitor processes every second
$exportIntervalInSeconds = 60  # Set the desired export interval
$iterationCount = 0
# Function to get CPU and Memory usage of a process
function Get-ProcessStats {
    param (
        [string]$processName
    )
    
    $process = Get-Process -Name $processName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    
    if ($process -ne $null) {
        $cpuUsage = $process.CPU
        $memoryUsage = $process.WorkingSet64
        Write-Output "$processName - CPU Usage: $cpuUsage%, Memory Usage: $memoryUsage bytes"
        # Create an object with process stats
        $statsObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
            ProcessName = $processName
            CPUUsage = $cpuUsage
            MemoryUsage = $memoryUsage
        }
        Write-Output "Stats: $statsObject"
        # Add the stats object to the array
        $processStats += $statsObject       
        Write-Output "ProcessStats:"
        $processStats | Format-Table
        $processStats.Count
    } else {
        Write-Output "$processName not found."
    }
}

# Loop to monitor processes every second
while ($true) {
    Get-ProcessStats -processName $process1Name
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    $iterationCount++
    # Clear-Host  # Optional: Clear the console for better readability
    if ($iterationCount -ge $exportIntervalInSeconds) {
        # Export the process stats to CSV
        Write-Output "Reached the iteration count greater than export interval"
        Write-Output "Exporting process stats to CSV:"
        $processStats | Format-Table
        Write-Output "Exporting..."
        $processStats | Export-Csv -Force -Path $csvFilePath -NoTypeInformation

        # Reset iteration count
        $iterationCount = 0
        $processStats = @()
    }
}
```

I dont see anything getting added in Stats.csv after regular intervals. In fact, the processStats does not contain anything. Interesting thing is the value of statsObject gets printed and the processStats value in the function Get-ProcessStats also gets printed but contains only 1 value at that moment. Not sure what is going wrong and why all the values are not getting printed and stored in CSV file.

Comment: Which debugger are you using? After hitting `Start-Sleep`, what is in the global array variable `$processStats`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You cannot populate the `$processStats` array you've initialized in the script [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Scopes) from a *function*, because functions run in a *child* scope of the caller (unless [dot-sourced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-)).
- To get this to work, you'd have to reference the variable directly in the caller's scope, which in your case means: `$script:processStats += $statsObject`
- However, from a code-maintenance perspective it is better *not* to modify variables across scope boundaries, and the PowerShell-idiomatic solution is to make the function *output* the object you want to add as an array element.

---

As for *why* your approach didn't work:

- While your function can *get* the caller's `$processStats` variable (value),  *setting* it creates a *local variable of the same name* that exists independently of the caller's variable, and goes out of scope when the function exits.
  Therefore, the caller doesn't see any modifications made to the (accidentally local) variable inside the function.<sup>[1]</sup>
- This behavior is somewhat counter-intuitive, especially with operators such as `+=`, where the new, local variable value is created *based on the original variable's value*.
- For a concise overview of scoping in PowerShell, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68613813/45375).

---

<sup>[1] Note that it is situationally possible to modify an *object* that a variable from an ancestral scope *references*, but this is unrelated to *variable scopes*. Specifically, if an ancestral variable happens to (a) contain an instance of a .NET *reference type* and (b) that type happens to have *methods* that mutate the state of an instance.

An example would be to create a [`[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.List-1) instance in your script scope, and then use its `.Add()` method from inside the function to add to it.

Even though arrays (instances of [`System.Array`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Array)) are .NET reference types too, they are *fixed-size*, so this approach cannot work; what PowerShell's `+=` operator does when "growing" arrays is to *create a new array* behind the scenes, formed from the original elements plus the one(s) being "appended". It is for this reason that using `+=` with arrays is generally best *avoided* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/45375).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the variable scope, function output and array modification mentioned by @mklement0, I'd like to note these changes:

- A usage of `foreach` instead of `if` for `$processList` to catch more than 1 value (process item) at that moment.
- `Write-Output` was replaced with `Write-Host` to avoid sending debug messages to the pipeline.
- Export was changed:

  - To alter the `CSV` file only when there was at least one process captured.
  - To `-Append` output to the file so it contains information from all iterations.

```
# Specify the process names
$process1Name = "abcd"
$csvFilePath = "C:\Users\johndoe\Stats.csv"
# Loop to monitor processes every second
$exportIntervalInSeconds = 60  # Set the desired export interval

# Function to get CPU and Memory usage of a process
function Get-ProcessStats {
    param (
        [string]$processName
    )
    
    $processList = Get-Process -Name $processName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    
    if ($processList.Count -eq 0) {
        Write-Host "$processName not found."
        return
    }

    foreach ($process in $processList) {
        $cpuUsage = $process.CPU
        $memoryUsage = $process.WorkingSet64
        Write-Host "$processName - CPU Usage: $cpuUsage%, Memory Usage: $memoryUsage bytes"
        
        # Create an object with process stats
        # It will be added to the function return array
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            ProcessName = $processName
            CPUUsage = $cpuUsage
            MemoryUsage = $memoryUsage
        }
    }
}

# Loop to monitor processes every second
while ($true) {
    $iterationCount = 0
    $processStats = while ($iterationCount -lt $exportIntervalInSeconds) {
        # Output of this function will be added to the $processStats list
        Get-ProcessStats -processName $process1Name
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        $iterationCount++
    }
    Write-Host "Reached the iteration count greater than export interval"
    
    # Export process stats if found
    if ($processStats.Count -gt 0) {
        Write-Host "Exporting process stats to CSV:"
        $processStats | Format-Table | Out-Host
        Write-Host "Exporting..."
        $processStats | Export-Csv -Force -Path $csvFilePath -NoTypeInformation -Append
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I've edited the code to use `Out-Host` instead.